# How to set maxBuffer in Judo

Tags: node.js, seo, phantomjs, snapshot

I'm using Judo.js to create sitemap and html snapshots of my Ember web application. Simple testing of basic urls on the site is failing. The sitemap is generated just fine however regardless of how many urls the urlConfig object contains (or how 'small' the pages are), it throws a "stdout maxBuffer exceeded" error.

First it logs `Preparing to snapshot: 2`(where 2 is # of urls I've specified).
Then it logs `Finished snapshotting: 2` 
However then it 'hangs' for approx 6 seconds and spits out:

```
 Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded]
    cmd: 'C:\Windows\\system31\\cmd.exe /s /c "phantom.js c:\\Temp\\visitlakesnapshots\\node_modules\\judo\\lib\\phantomjs-runner.js
 http://www.mywebsite.com/dine"
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I modify the maxBuffer for phantom? It doesn't seem like one page would exceed the request size though.

**EDIT:** 
When I just run a very small page....make sure it is under 200K, it works. And I found documentation that maxBuffer default is 200K. So I need to know how to increase the maxBuffer option when using judo. I found this but not sure how to incorporate it into my existing code:

```
var execute = function(command, callback){
    exec(command, {maxBuffer: 1024 * 500}, function(error, stdout, stderr){
           callback(error, stdout); });
};
```

Below is my script file I run with Node:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   //res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');


var options = {
   muteWarnings: false,   // mute warnings generated by Judo
    phantomProcs: 5      // Number of PhantomJS processes to run concurrently. Had 1 here, changed to 5...makes no difference.
};

var Judo = require('judo');
var judo = new Judo(options);


var urlConfig = {
    baseUrl: 'http://www.visitlakefl.com',     // The base URL of your site
    siteMapPath: 'E:/Websites/VisitLake/sitemap.xml',  // Sitemap output
    snapshotsDir: 'E:/Websites/VisitLake/Views/Snapshots',
    urls: [
        {
            url: '/',
            siteMap: {   changefreq: 'daily' },
            snapshot: { changefreq: 'daily',filenames: ['index.html','home.html']}
        },
         {
            url: '/play',
            siteMap: {   changefreq: 'daily' },
            snapshot: { changefreq: 'daily',filenames: ['play/index.html']}
        },
        {
           url: '/dine',
           siteMap: {  changefreq: 'daily'},
           snapshot: {changefreq: 'daily',filenames: ['dine/index.html']}
       }
    ]
};


//judo.updateSiteMap(urlConfig, function(err){
    //if (!err) console.log('that was easy!');
//});

judo.createSnapshots(urlConfig, function(err){
    if (!err) { console.log('snapshots created. That was easy!');
           process.exit();
        } else { 
      console.log(err);
           process.exit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My [PR](https://github.com/jasich/judo.js/pull/3) which addresses this issue has been merged. If you get the latest version of Judo from [GitHub](https://github.com/jasich/judo.js), You can now specify a `maxBuffer` setting in options, like this:

```
var options = {
    muteWarnings: false,        // Allows the user to mute warnings generated by Judo
    phantomProcs: 1,            // Number of PhantomJS processes to run concurrently
    maxBuffer: 200*1024         // Max PhantomJS output buffer size
};

var judo = new Judo(options);
```

The error go away once you set the maxBuffer to a value larger than the largest page on your site.